# (tf2.keras) InternalError: Recorded operation 'GradientReversalOperator' returned too few gradients. Expected 3 but received 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

My code is available on [github](https://github.com/xiqxin1/dann-tf.keras-test/tree/main/danntest).

I wrote a custom gradient layer as follow:

```py
@tf.custom_gradient
def GradientReversalOperator(x, lambdal):
    def grad(dy):
        return lambdal * tf.negative(dy)
    return x, grad


class GradientReversalLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, lambdal):
        super(GradientReversalLayer, self).__init__()
        self.lambdal = lambdal

    def call(self, inputs):
        return GradientReversalOperator(inputs, self.lambdal)
```

If I remove `lambdal`, everything works fine. But when I add it back, I get the error:

> InternalError: Recorded operation 'GradientReversalOperator' returned too few gradients. Expected 3 but received 2

Some answers report I should make one more fake return value, but the error becomes "too many gradients". The Traceback is as follow:

> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in **exit**
> self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2804, in variable_creator_scope
> yield
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1695, in train_on_batch
> logs = train_function(iterator)
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in **call**
> result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 823, in _call
> self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 697, in _initialize
> *args, **kwds))
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
> graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
> graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
> capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
> func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
> return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
> File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
> raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: in user code:
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
> return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
> return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
> outputs = model.train_step(data)
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:757 train_step
> self.trainable_variables)
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:2722 _minimize
> gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py:1073 gradient
> unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
> D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\imperative_grad.py:77 imperative_grad
> compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))
> InternalError: Recorded operation 'GradientReversalOperator' returned too few gradients. Expected 3 but received 2

Comment: The code you have posted does not reproduce your error. Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem,
try this:

```
class GradientReversal(Layer):
    '''Flip the sign of gradient during training.'''

    @tf.custom_gradient
    def grad_reverse(self, x):
        y = tf.identity(x)
        def custom_grad(dy):
            return -self.hp_lambda * dy
        return y, custom_grad

    # --------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, hp_lambda, **kwargs):
        super(GradientReversal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hp_lambda = K.variable(hp_lambda, dtype='float32',     name='hp_lambda')


    # --------------------------------------
    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        return self.grad_reverse(x)

    # --------------------------------------
    def set_hp_lambda(self,hp_lambda):
        #self.hp_lambda = hp_lambda
        K.set_value(self.hp_lambda, hp_lambda)

    # --------------------------------------
    def increment_hp_lambda_by(self,increment):
        new_value = float(K.get_value(self.hp_lambda)) +  increment
        K.set_value(self.hp_lambda, new_value)

# --------------------------------------
    def get_hp_lambda(self):
        return float(K.get_value(self.hp_lambda))
```